# Need help understanding a proof on modules over group algebras

Tags: representation-theory, algebras

I'm trying to understand a sketch of a proof that the group ring $k[C_p^2]$ has infinitely many non-isomorphic 2-dimensional (i.e, length 2) indecomposable modules. I need help with some details, and I add my comments, so somebody can correct me if I'm thinking wrong. It goes as follows:

$A=k[G]$ is local. Denote it's maximal ideal by $M$, which is the augmentation ideal. (I don't know if it's important for this proof to know that it's the augmentation ideal.)

$\dim_k(M/M^2)\geq 2$; for otherwise $\dim_k(M/M^2)=1$ implies $\dim_k(A)=\dim_k(A/M^p)=p$ a contradiction. (The implication is because of the sequence $A\supset M\supset M^2 \supset \dots \supset M^p=0$ I guess).

From this point I totally lost track.

When $I$ ranges over the hyperplanes of $M/M^2$, the $A/(M^2+I)$ form pairwise non-isomorphic 2-dimensional indecomposable modules.

As far as I know, hyperplanes of $M/M^2$ are subspaces of $M/M^2$ of codimension 1. Do I need to think them as $I/M^2$ to think $A/(M^2+I)$. Even if that's the case, how can I say there are infinitely many non-isomorphic of these.

If this need geometric concepts, just point me to the right direction with some details of the proof please.

Edit: This proof is from a comment that I took screenshot at mathoverflow from the user [Ycor](https://mathoverflow.net/users/14094/ycor)

Comment: I guess $A=k[G]$?

Comment: Yes, I added that, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Let $I\subset M$ be a submodule with $I/M^2$ a hyperplane of $M/M^2$. Then $I$ is in particular an ideal of $A$ and the annihilator of $A/I$ is precisely $I$.

So if $A/I\simeq A/J$, then their annihilators are the same, so $I=J$: they are all pairwise nonisomorphic.

Now the "geometry" part is that since $M/M^2$ is of dimension at least $2$, it has infinitely many hyperplanes, which is a standard fact of linear algebra.

Then you also need to figure out why $A/I$ is indecomposable and of dimension $2$, but you didn't ask specifically for those, so I don't know if you want the proofs. If you do, ask me in the comments.

Comment: Before seeing this answer I figure out that I don't know why $I$ becomes an ideal of $A$ and don't see that why $M^p=0$ yet.
I already got the "infinitely many hyperplane" part by choosing a basis ${b_1,...b_n}$ and changing it to ${b_1,c.b_1+b_2,...,c.b_1+b_n}$, the components 2 to n with first one arbitrary defines a hyperplane. So for every $c\in k$ there is a hyperplane.
The indecomposibility and dimension 2 is still not clear to me.

Comment: I guess dimesion 2 follows since any proper submodule of $A/I$ has type $X/I$ with $A\supset X \supseteq I$ and maximality of $M$ in $A$ implies $M\supseteq X\supseteq I$ but then $M/I$ has dimension 1 gives $X=M$ or $X=I$. So the submodule lattice of $A/I$ is just $A/I\supseteq M/I\supseteq I/I$.

Comment: For the indecomposability part, I think something but might be wrong. If $A/I$ has a nontrivial decomposition as $X/I \bigoplus Y/I$, intersecting with $M/I$ gives $(X\cap M)/I \bigoplus (Y\cap M)/I$ but $M/I$ being 1 dimesional gives one of them equals $M/I$ and other $0$. If WLOG $(X\cap M)/I=M/I$ then $X\supseteq M$ gives $X=M$ since the decomposition is nontrivial. Now the unique maximal $M/I$ of $A/I$ is a direct summand seems absurd to me, since in that case there must be a complement which does not lie in the unique maximal of $A/I$.